# Using tooltips on an image map in a content editor web part Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, web-part, content-editor-web-part

I am trying to add pop-up tooltips on mouse hover over an image map delivered by a content editor web part (HTML stored as a .txt file in the pages library) on a site in SharePoint 2010.

Is this possible? Has anyone done this? Please note that I do not have access to SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the "Title" attribute to the `<area>` tags to add built-in browser tool tips.

For example:

```
<img usemap="#mymap" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
<map name="mymap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,24,48" href="http://www.bing.com" title="Go to Bing" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="24,0,48,48" href="http://www.google.com" title="Go to Google" />
</map>
```

[image: hovering over left image brings up "go to bing" tooltip]
[image: hovering over right image brings up "go to google" tooltip]

Comment: You can also try this online image map generator: http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de. If you don't have SharePoint designer - just use Content Editor Web part